# Problem with the Manipulate command

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, manipulate, evaluation

I am trying to upload a notebook with the following code to my blog, but every time I upload it,  the "manipulate" code does not give anything. Do I have to change anything?

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{sol}, 
  eqns = {s'[t] == -λ[t]*s[t], 
    i'[t] == λ[t]*s[t] - γ*i[t], 
    r'[t] == γ*i[t], v'[t] == 0, s[0] == (1 - p)*n, i[0] == 1, 
    r[0] == 0, v[0] == p*(n - 1)};
  sol = NDSolve[eqns, {s, i, r, v}, {t, 0, tMax1}];
  Plot[Evaluate[{s[t], i[t], r[t], v[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tMax1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green, {Black, Dashed}}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Susceptible", "Infected", "Recovered", 
     "Vaccinated"}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Population"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Epidemic Dynamics", ImageSize -> 400]], {{γ, 
   0.1, "Recovery rate (γ)"}, 0.01, 1, 
  0.01}, {{β, 0.5, "Infection rate (β)"}, 0.01, 1, 
  0.01}, {{p, 0.3, "Vaccination coverage (p)"}, 0, 1, 0.01}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: What is `n`,  `tMax1` etc. Please post the complete code.

Comment: @cvgmt   $ tMax1$ is 100 days and $n$ is the population $10^6$

Comment: What is `λ[t]`?

Comment: **but every time I upload it, the "manipulate" code does not give anything** I did not know that now Manipulate runs on the internet? How does it work? you say you upload Manipulate to your blog. Does this mean others can run it in your blog? Since when this became possible?

Comment: @Nasser it is the first time that I am trying something like this. As I can understand from your comment, it is not possible

Comment: As far as I know, you can't run Manipulate on your blog like this. Unless you are on Wolfram cloud or using WOLFRAM APPLICATION SERVER or something like this. Only option now is to have someone download the CDF file you make from your manipulate and then use the Wolfram player to run it.  Long time ago there used to be a way to run Manipulate directly in the browser but this long gone.  The same thing happened to Java applets. Can't run them anymore in the browser. All due to security,